# Ingress DNS doesn't work outside container

Tags: kubectl, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress, metallb

I have an ingress deployed in a k8s cluster in VMware. The issue is that the DNS responds inside the container:

```
[root@k8s-cluster ~]# kubectl exec -it -n test ingress-nginx-controller-848bfcb64d-n796z  -- curl localhost/banana -H 'Host: k8s-cluster.lab.buch.int'
banana
```

But if I try from the cluster:

```
[root@k8s-cluster ~]# curl localhost/banana
curl: (7) Failed connect to localhost:80; Connection refused
```

It doesn't work even if I use the DNS instead of localhost or the IP assigned by metallb to the ingress controller.

```
[root@k8s-cluster ~]# kubectl get services
NAME                                 TYPE           CLUSTER-IP       EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)                      AGE
apple-service                        ClusterIP      10.97.109.66     <none>        5678/TCP                     6d15h
banana-service                       ClusterIP      10.110.129.29    <none>        5678/TCP                     6d15h
ingress-nginx-controller             LoadBalancer   10.99.151.233    10.133.2.21   80:31981/TCP,443:30293/TCP   6d15h
ingress-nginx-controller-admission   ClusterIP      10.108.116.127   <none>        443/TCP                      6d15h
```

```
[root@k8s-cluster ~]# kubectl describe ing
Warning: extensions/v1beta1 Ingress is deprecated in v1.14+, unavailable in v1.22+; use networking.k8s.io/v1 Ingress
Name:             example-ingress
Namespace:        test
Address:          10.133.65.148
Default backend:  default-http-backend:80 (<error: endpoints "default-http-backend" not found>)
Rules:
  Host                            Path  Backends
  ----                            ----  --------
  k8s-cluster.lab.buch.int
                                  /apple(/|$)(.*)    apple-service:5678 (192.168.86.184:5678)
                                  /banana(/|$)(.*)   banana-service:5678 (192.168.76.157:5678)
Annotations:                      kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
                                  nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$2
Events:                           <none>
```

If I curl the external ip assigned by metallb: 10.133.2.21

```
[root@k8s-cluster ~]# curl 10.133.2.21
<html>
<head><title>404 Not Found</title></head>
<body>
<center><h1>404 Not Found</h1></center>
```

So, it means that the nginx works in a some way, but if I try to curl 10.133.2.21/banana or 10.133.2.21/apple it doesn't work.

Any ideas?

Comment: How did you deploy `Nginx Ingress controller`? What K8s version are you using? It's Minikube or Kubeadm? Can you provide logs form Ingress Controller?

Answer (score 0):

In your `Ingress` configuration, you specified **k8s-cluster.lab.buch.int** host, therefore you can reach `apple` and `banana` services using this specific hostname:

```
curl k8s-cluster.lab.buch.int/apple
```

and

```
curl k8s-cluster.lab.buch.int/banana
```

**Solution**

If you change `Ingress` host to `*` (all hosts) which is default configuration, or remove this field from your YAML.

```
...
rules:
- host: "k8s-cluster.lab.buch.int" ### Here you can change to "*" or remove this field
  http:
    paths:
    - path: "/apple(/|$)(.*)"
      backend:
...
```

With above change you will be able to reach your services using `LoadBalancer` IP address:

```
$ curl 10.133.2.21/apple
```

and

```
$ curl 10.133.2.21/banana
```

As you can read in Kubernetes [Ingress rules](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/#ingress-rules) docs:

> Both the host and path must match the content of an incoming request before the load balancer directs traffic to the referenced Service.

In addition, `404 Not Found` when you are trying to `$ curl 10.133.2.21` and `$ curl k8s-cluster.lab.buch.int` is expected behavior, as you didn't set [default-backend](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/#default-backend)

> Default backend:  default-http-backend:80 (<error: endpoints "default-http-backend" not found>)